# how to use each to pass sets of variables to a function in q

Tags: kdb

I have a function that deletes and works using a directory and a table and column as variables:

```
Delete1[dir,t,c]
```

Another that retruns a set of directories that works:

```
Paths[dir]
```

Now I am trying to combine these two using something like "each" to all the directories that Paths[dir] to Delete1 function and I am trying something like this:

```
Delete1 each (Paths[dir];t;c)
```

The syntax does not quite work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [projection](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/application/#projection). Supplying only the second and third arguments to the `Delete1` function creates a new function with just one argument. You can use each between the projection and `Paths`

```
Delete1[;t;c] each Paths[dir]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use dot apply to this end, you can read more about dot applies here https://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply. It would look like the following:

```
Delete1 .' (Paths[dir];t;c)
```

Note if you're using this delete function to delete a column from a table in every partition you only need to delete it from .d file in the last partition. (like in a previous question of yours [soft deleting a column from a table in q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520417/soft-deleting-a-column-from-a-table-in-q) )